# where to add folder path in asp.net core instead of harcoding it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, appsettings

I have a list of folder locations in my application.

How do I add folder path location in the app without hardcoding it.

I found web.config to use appsettings but I cannot load it in my Visual studio 
and what is the different between appsetting.config and web config

Comment: _"but I cannot load it in my Visual studio"_ - Something is _very wrong_ with your Visual Studio in that case. Please note that the `asp.net` and `asp.net-core` tags are mutually exclusive.

Comment: _“How do I add folder path location in the app”_ – What do you even mean with that? What is it that you want to do?

Comment: @jasper kent, answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appsettings.config has replaced web.config in ASP.NET Core.

appsettings.config is where you should but and confirmation information for your application.

Data in appsettings.config can be accessed in the program via the `IConfiguration` interface, which is available as a property in the `Startup` class, and can be accessed in controllers etc. through dependency injection.

Full details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark as a correct answer if you're happy.